# Will Sabre Cat ever respawn for Aela's quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been completing Aela's quests having completed the main Companion questline in order to obtain the Totems of Hircine.

She gave me the Animal Extermination task of clearing Greenspring Hollow in Whiterun of a Sabre Cat, which I had already done for her earlier. When I arrived the previously defeated Sabre Cat was there. What I ended up doing next was casting Raise Zombie on it before it died and turned to ash.
Now everytime I return (it's been over 30 in-game days now, I just used wait in Breezehome) the pile of ash remains and the quest pointer points to it as if I should defeat this.

My question is will the Sabre Cat ever respawn so I can complete the quest?

I'm playing on a PS3, so unfortunately cannot use mods to fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the Sabre Cat will never respawn, at least on the current version of Skyrim (1.3), due to a bug. The current [changelog](http://www.bethblog.com/2012/01/19/news-on-the-creation-kit-and-game-updates/) for version 1.4 states, under the bug fix section:

> - Fixed issue with ash piles not cleaning up properly

I had previously waited over 31 days in multiple locations away from the Sabre Cat's ash pile to no avail, hopefully when 1.4 lands I'll be able to complete the quest.

Answer (score 0):

Respawning is something that happens to everyone, like a Sabre Cat. But the ones that turn to ash, they have never come back for me so im not sure if you will see him again. Just wait, skip those quest and to many more, then go back to it.